# Angular map or mergeMap

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple JSON file which returns an array of objects in format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "file/abc.txt"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "file/def.txt"
    }
]
```

I am accessing the service as given below:

```
this.http.get("json-url")
.map((response) => response.json())
.filter((file) => file.id === 1)
```

It doesn't work anything. However if I use mergeMap instead, it works fine.

```
this.http.get("api-url")
.mergeMap((response) => response.json())
.filter((file) => file.id === 1)
```

I have used **map** operator earlier and it worked. However it is not working here. Please let me know if I am mistaking anything while using **map** operator.

Please note- I am using angular 6.

Comment: which version of RxJs are you using? If you are using RxJs 6 or above, you have to use the `pipe` operator, whereas earlier version allows you to directly apply `map` operator on an `Observable`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this doesn't work"?

Comment: rxjs version - 5.5.6

Comment: @pgreen2: updated question

Comment: add the error message you are encountering.

Comment: If you're using angular 6, you're not using rxjs 5.5.6 (at least you wouldn't do that usually). In angular 6, we're not using `.map((response) => response.json())` at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Angular 6, it's really recommended to use `HttpClient` as `Http` is deprecated. Now since you'd be using `HttpClient` you won't need to call `.json` method on the `response` as that is something that `HttpClient` takes care of implicitly.

Also, since Angular 6 uses Rxjs 5.5 or later, you can't directly chain the operators like `map` and `pipe` to an `Observable`. You'll have to call the `pipe` function on an `Observable` value and add the list of operators that you want to you separated by a `,`.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

...

return this.http.get("json-url")
  .pipe(filter((file) => file.id === 1));
```

Here, I'm returning the `Observable` so that I can `subscribe` to it from the place I'm calling the function that is wrapping this piece of code.

To make sure that `HttpClient` works correctly, you'll also have to import `HttpClientModule` in your `@NgModule` file and add it to the `imports` array.

Answer (score 1):

Important to understand here is that `this.http.get("json-url")` returns an observable. It won't be executed until you subscribe. You must subscribe to send the request.

`this.http.get("json-url")
.map((response) => response.json())
.filter((file) => file.id === 1)
.subscribe(theResultAfterMapAndFilter => console.log(theResultAfterMapAndFilter));`

The reason why `mergeMap` works is that it subscribes to the source observable internally (if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for why `map` isn't working, but i'm not entirely sure why `mergeMap` is working. The object returned from `response.json()` is any list.  So the `filter` should handle the full list.  Not the individual elements of the list.  The list has not property of `id` so nothing matches.  Even though the parameter in `filter` is called `file`, it should be `files`.  I believe the following will work with map:

```
this.http.get("json-url")
.map((response) => response.json())
.filter((files) => files.filter((file)->file.id === 1));
```

However, you would get a list back.  If you really want a single file, you could add in another map:

```
this.http.get("json-url")
.map((response) => response.json())
.filter((files) => files.filter((file)->file.id === 1))
.map(files=> files[0]);
```

With all of that said, I think the reason `mergeMap` worked might be some older quirk of rxjs.  My unverified guess is that list returned from the anonymous function is being converted into an observable by `mergeMap`.  That seems a bit fishy, but could be possible.  The older rxjs API seemed to try to make things work even if it probably shouldn't.